# Wifi does not show up in the Gnome UI

Tags: centos, wifi

The wifi isn't showing up in the network manager in Gnome. There is a wifi entry along with wired, but it doesn't show any SSID. The wifi is enabled and the hardware shows up when I run lspci, and even the firmware shows up in /lib/firmware.

It's not soft or hard blocked when running rfkill. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I think its network manager issue. I had something similar happen to me, you can check my profile its my only question.

I executed iwconfig

```
$ sudo iwlist scan wlan0
```

and the card was there but it was down (iwlist scan failed)

so I run these commands to bring it up manually:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
service network-manager restart
```

If that doesnt work, you could try and fix it by a very simple step, namely modifying /etc/network/interfaces by removing (or commenting out using #) the following two lines:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

And lastly if youre connected to the internet you could try clicking System>Administration>Aditional Drivers (This will bring up non open-drivers)